# SQL query for time range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with two TIME columns: `time_from` and `time_to`. Now I need to select all rows where time_from > *currentTime* and time_to < *currentTime*.
For example, **time_from** is 22:00, **time_to** is 2:00 and now is 23:45. In this case 2:00 is for tomorrow and this row should be selected. Can someone point me right query?

Comment: If you need to take times from different days, maybe you should change your table to a `DATETIME`, instead of `TIME`, and use `BETWEEN`.

Comment: With `DATETIME` I'd need to specify date, but this `between` term should be used everyday.

Comment: `BETWEEN` [should be avoided for date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - and this _does_ apply to MySQL, as sub-second precision can be specified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with `TIME` values, I'd trust this Query:

```
select *
from TEST
where
(time_from < time_to and cast(NOW() as TIME) between time_from and time_to)
or
(time_from > time_to and cast(NOW() as TIME) > time_from)
or
(time_from > time_to and cast(NOW() as TIME) < time_to);
```

It safely compares the times even when they overpass the day time (e.g.: `from 22:00 to 02:00`).

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8afa0/8)

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   NOW() between time_from and time_to
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but if his columns are from `TIME` type, aren't they undestood as `1970/01/01 HH:MM:SS` and thus breaking the `NOW()` comparison?

Comment: If `time_from`, `time_to` and `NOW()` are in the same day, `BETWEEN` works correctly. But if the period ends the next day, these rows are not selected. May be I need one more term for the case when `time_to < time_from` (means tomorrow)?

Comment: If `time_to` contains both a date and a time, this query should work.  If it only contains a time, how would you tell if it is today's or tomorrow's?